# Объединить два репозитория

Tags: git

У меня возникла проблема, нужно объединить два репозитория, ситуация следующая:

- Я создаю проект бэкенда, он находится в папке `MyProject`.
- Внутри я создаю папку `frontend` и создаю в ней второй проект. Так
  получилось, что скрипт, который инициализирует данный проект, также
  производит инициализацию git-репозитория.

И таким образом, когда я в главной папке `MyProject` выполняю создание репозитория, то git не видит файлы в папке `frontend`, потому что это уже второй репозиторий.

Иерархия следующая:

```
 -- MyProject
 ---- frontend
```

Не чего не клонировалось обе папки инициализировались через `git init`

Вопрос: как мне второй репозиторий `frontend` слить с первым, чтобы у меня был всего один целый репозиторий `MyProject`?

Comment: несколько сложно догадаться, что вы имеете в виду. возможно, вам всего лишь надо удалить каталог `frontend/.git`

Comment: Тогда еще раз.
Есть репозиторий `MyProject` внутри него есть репозиторий `frontend`, я хочу что бы папка `frontend` перестала быть репозиторием и все файлы внутри этой папки принадлежали репозиторию `MyProject`.

Comment: @Swagga дайте иерархию ваших папок в вопросе. и скажите, какие создали с командой `git clone`?

Comment: ну, значит, так и сделайте: удалите упомянутый каталог и программа *git* внезапно «увидит» содержимое каталога `frontend`. если у вас ещё нет резервной копии, лучше её перед этим сделать.

Comment: @Swagga мне кажется если удалишь из папки `frontend` папку `.git` то уже в верхней будет она видна `git` -у как новая созданная, таким образом в ней будет общая репозитория.

Comment: @Swagga когда попробуете дайте знать, мне то же интересно что будет.

Comment: Вас понял, возможно это то что мне нужно, попробую, потому что репозиторий в папке frontend мне абсолютно не нужен, спасибо!

Comment: историю frontend сохранять надо? если нет, то удалите из него папку .git. Если нужно историю сохранить - это сложнее, но возможно. Как альтернатива - подключите второй репозиторий как субмодуль. Субмодуль на вид очень простой вариант, только потом можно намучиться с ним

Comment: Нет история `frontend` меня абсолютно не интересует, я просто хочу что бы данные проекты для git были как один.

Comment: Тогда в первом комментарии уже все написано.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## короткий ответ:

вам всего лишь надо удалить каталог `frontend/.git`

после этого программа *git*, запущенная в, например, каталоге `myproject`, «увидит» и содержимое каталога `frontend`

## длинный ответ с пояснениями:

если программе *git* при её вызове не был явно указан (параметрами или переменными окружения) путь к *хранилищу* («репозиторию»), первым делом она его (т.е., каталог `.git`) ищет. сначала в текущем каталоге, затем в вышестоящем, и так далее. а *рабочим каталогом* (если он тоже не был явно указан параметром или переменной окружения) будет считаться тот, в котором находится подкаталог `.git` (т.е. само *хранилище*).

многие из команд, понимаемых программой *git*, требуют просмотра *рабочего каталога* — *work tree* (и вложенных каталогов, разумеется) на предмет изменений (например, `status`, `diff` и т.д.).

и если при просмотре под-каталогов *рабочего каталога* в каком-нибудь из них будет обнаружен каталог (или файл) с именем `.git`, то программа *git* будет считать, что этот под-каталог является *рабочим каталогом* для какого-то другого *git-хранилища*, и его содержимое надо игнорировать.

именно такая ситуация и описана в вопросе.

и если содержимое *хранилища* в каталоге `frontend/.git` не нужно, то его можно удалять. тогда программа *git* «увидит» содержимое каталога `frontend` — бывшего *рабочего каталога* для *хранилища*, располагавшегося в каталоге `frontend/.git`

Comment: Небольшая поправка, если я правильно помню, то с версии 2.5.0 либо каталог, либо файл со ссылкой на основное дерево, где уже реальный *.git* каталог расположен.

Comment: начало цитаты *каталог (**или файл**) с именем `.git`* конец цитаты

Comment: По тексту смотрим: "...его (т.е., каталог .git) ...", "...подкаталог .git...", "...этот подкаталог является рабочим каталогом...". В одном месте из пяти без упоминания как это работает.